# Sinon stub pass through arguments

Tags: javascript, node.js, sinon

I want to be able to just return the arguments that a stub receives passed to a promise, is this possible:

Impl:

```
function(arg) {
   return db.find(arg)
     .then(result => {
        return fnIWantToStub(result);
      })
      .then(nextResult => {
         return done()
      });
```

Test:

```
var stub = sinon.stub(fnIWantToStub);
stub.returns(PassedThruArgsThatReturnsAPromise);
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 2):

The [docs](http://sinonjs.org/releases/v1.17.7/stubs/) state that you can return an arg at a given index.

```
stub.returnsArg(index);
```

I don't think there is a blanket return all args.

(UPDATE after question edit)

You could stub the db.find function and resolve it. I use mocha and chai.

```
const dbStub = sinon.stub(db, 'find');
const expected = {..};
dbStub.returns(Promise.resolve(someDataFixture));
const result = functionUnderTest(args);
// using chaiAsPromised
return expect(result).to.eventually.equal(expected);
```

Note you have to return to get Mocha to run through the promise. You can also use mocha's done callback. Although quite often I'll just use a Promise.

Checkout http://staxmanade.com/2015/11/testing-asyncronous-code-with-mochajs-and-es7-async-await/

Comment: Updated question, my apologies.  Yes this works, but I'm trying to get to return the args wrapped in a Promise.resolve

Comment: OK. let me delete that answer then because it isn't relevant. Will post a new one.

Comment: I actually updated the existing one. I hope that makes sense.